# Could not set the title of tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I embedded tableviewcontroller into a navigation controller, set the title, but it does not show when I run the app.
What is wrong?
[image]

This is the setting of the tableviewcontroller
[image]

Here is the setting of the navigation controller

[image]

Comment: Check the frame of the table view. It looks like tableview is starting from 0. I think it should start from 44.

Comment: How did you show that ViewController? Instanciate it? Clearly, The NavController isn't the initialVC of the storyboard, and if you instanciate it, you need to use it's nav controller.

Comment: where to check it?

Comment: @Lame: I drag and drop the TableViewController. I also tick on "Is initial View Controller", but it does not hep

Comment: can you please take a screenshot of the setting of your TableViewController?

Comment: @Siyavash I added

Comment: Where is the code of you creating the TableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

First check, your NavVC must be initial VC.
If not then try this piece of code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I add swift code: self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true). but it does not help

Comment: Have you added TabBarController ?

Answer (score 0):

you must be presenting the plain table view instead of navigation controller. What you need to do is make you tableview as root view for a navigation controller and present the navigation controller.

```
 var nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
 //then present the nav
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the initial VC from Navigation Controller to your TableViewController

Answer (score 0):

I did not set the StoryboardId for Navigation controller.